# IIS one request on two sites

Tags: iis

My problem is that our production app sometime crash. We can't simulate it on our B site and would like to be able to debug it. But it would mean to connect on production site A and stop it for too long time.
Is there any way how to pass requests to site A also to site B? So site A would work as normal and site B would just catch these requests and when there is a problem we could debug it and site A would still work?
Or it's stupid and unreal idea?

Comment: What kind of crash? If `w3wp.exe` crashes for unknown reasons, capture crash dumps and that's the only common way to go.

Comment: It's .net core app, running on IIS. And my problem is out of memory, so not easy to catch it.

Comment: According to your description, it is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: support.microsoft.com.

Comment: .NET Core has its own tools which are available cross platform, so if you like you can try to see if you hit the simplest cases and help yourself out, https://www.tessferrandez.com/blog/2021/03/18/debugging-a-netcore-memory-issue-with-dotnet-dump.html But like @samwu suggested, very likely you need some help from others, such as Microsoft support.

Comment: Possilbe to use Postman to send off the request to your site B?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use Postman. But we found it's possible to instal ARR on IIS, run our app twice and when we see that one off them has 99% CPU load, we can just simply "shut  down" that instance in ARR, debug it and traffic will now go only on second, healthy instance.